# Leaflet R coordinate

Tags: r, leaflet, rstudio

I'm working with Rstudio to create a dynamic map. Currently, I'm learning how to use and code leaflet and I have a problem with coordinates. I'm following a basic tutorial that shows how to put a marker on the map.

```
library(leaflet)
library(shiny)
m = leaflet()
m = addTiles(m)
m = addMarkers(m, lng=-123,256169, lat=49,266063, popup="T")
m
```

On the tutorial, this point is in a street:

[image: Picture from the tuto]

and in the Rstudio viewer the point is in the sea:

[image: picture from my Rstudio]

I tried with others point with others tutorials, and the result is the same. My point is not at the correct place.

Comment: you should link to the tutorial's webpage as well so we can see them to compare.

Comment: I just dropped them on a map and they are on land, but  I had to remove the commas and use a period to represent decimals to make it work....have you tried this?

Comment: @sconfluentus you're right. I'm french and for the decimal we use the comas. I use the period and it works. thank you